# problem with polygon_90_data and vertices

Tags: c++11, boost, polygon, boost-polygon

I create a boost polygon with 5 vertices, but when I display the vertices or

```
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
.
.
.

void displayPolygon(boost::polygon::polygon_90_data<int> const& polygon, std::string name)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "polygon "  << name << std::endl;
    for (boost::polygon::polygon_90_data<int>::iterator_type it = polygon.begin(); it != polygon.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).x() << "/" << (*it).y() << "->";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
.
.
.
void testPolygon2()
{
    //typedef
    typedef boost::polygon::polygon_90_data<int> Polygon90Type;
    typedef std::vector<Polygon90Type> Polygon90Set;

    typedef boost::polygon::polygon_data<int> PolygonType;
    typedef std::vector<PolygonType> PolygonSet;
    typedef boost::polygon::point_data<int> PointType;
    typedef std::vector<PointType> PointSet;

    typedef boost::polygon::polygon_traits<Polygon90Type>::point_type Point;

    Polygon90Type polygon_1;

    Point pts_1[6] = { Point(0,0), Point(0,10), Point(5,12), Point(10,10), Point(10,0), Point(0,0)};

    polygon_1.set(pts_1, pts_1 + 6);
    std::cout << "polygon_1 area is " << boost::polygon::area(polygon_1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << __LINE__ << " : 
    Polygon90Set polygonSet;

    polygonSet.push_back(polygon_1);
    //an attempt to see result of bloating with 0
    boost::polygon::bloat(polygonSet, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    std::cout << "nb polygon bloated " << polygonSet.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto polygon : polygonSet)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << __LINE__ << "####################################" << std::endl;
        displayPolygon(polygon, "2 - after being bloated");

        std::cout << "area is " << boost::polygon::area(polygon) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the area it does not correspond to the polygon created.
the area should be 110 but is displayed as 100?
the vertices should be (0,0), (0,10), (5,12), (10,10), (10,0) but are (0/10), (5/10) ,(5/10), (10/10), (10/0), (0/0). It looks like the point (/5/12) is dismissed and replaced with point (5/10).
What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: What is the reason that you are using `polygon_90_data` instead of `polygon_data` ? Two quotes from polygon reference which refers to 90_data "*angles are restricted to multiples of 90 degrees*" and "*The semantic of a polygon_90 is that it can provide iterators over the x and y coordinates that correspond to its horizontal and vertical sides, starting with an x coordinate.* ". When area is calculated for 90polygon these restrictions are considered and result is not what you expected. Use `polygon_data`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer and you are right. I am now going to go through the bloat and shrink function to see if it fullfills my goal.